# Any way to wrap a long string in Xcode to new line?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have word-wrapping disabled in Xcode and I try to limit every line to 120 characters. But what can I do when I have a really long string that breaks this limit? I can't find a clean way to wrap it to a new line in Xcode without creating multiple strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are using the Swift tag, I'll assume you're programming in swift.

Swift supports multiline strings like this:

```
var about: String = """
My name is Adam.
I am a software developer.
"""
```

This will include a newline character at the end of each line. To remove the newline character add a `\` to the end of the line.

Example:

```
var about: String = """
My name is Adam. \
I am a software developer.
"""
```

[Swift Reference for Multiline Strings](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html)

Comment: I knew about `"""` but didn't know the forward-slash trick.

Comment: I think no need for the `\` at the end - the auto line break thing only happens between lines

Comment: @aheze between lines?

Comment: @adambcomer sorry I put a backslash "\", but it didn't show up. The auto newline only happens between `Adam.` and `I`

Comment: @aheze That is correct. I'll update it.